# How to use WHERE CLAUSE in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-4

Hello i have 2 tables Student & Faculty
i want to call them to my index(view), So I figured how to join them. but I have a problem, I need to divide these 2 tables into a category but I don't know the code. Can someone please help me?

```
 public function getStudentReguler()
{
    return $this->db->table('student')
        ->join('faculty', 'faculty.id_faculty = student.id_student')
        ->where('category', *i want to be like, where categor = A*)
        ->get()->getResultArray();
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getStudentReguler()
{
    return $this->db->table('student')
        ->join('faculty', 'faculty.id_faculty = student.id_student')
        ->where('category', 'A')
        ->get()->getResultArray();
}
```

Please try this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from('student')
->join('faculty', 'faculty.id_faculty = student.id_student')
->where('category', 'A')
->get()->getResultArray();
```

Comment: I am not an php developer. But trying to help. What's the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: opps my problem, there was a typo. but it helped a lot, thank you!!

Comment: You are most welcome. It's great to know that the problen ia resolved. best wiahes.